# Duvida no Windows Form em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Sou um programador iniciante, tive algumas matérias na faculdade sobre Java e C++,e estou tentando aprender C# por conta própria.

Para isso,estou tentando fazer um aplicativo (Windows Form) que vai ter textos,escolhas,e imagens,como se fosse um jogo (bem básico).

Eu coloquei algumas imagens,alguns eventos que quando o usuário clicar em um botão,vai mostrar uma imagem. Mas essas imagens estão salvas no meu computador,então imagino que quando eu mandar o "Arquivo.exe" pra algum outro computador,o programa não vai achar as imagens.

O que eu faço ? Como eu deixo as imagens ''embutidas'' no programa?

Como eu sou iniciante, agradeço se puderem simplificar pra mim, sem complicar muito!